# Как поменять цвет перетащенного элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css, simple-html-dom

Стоит задача поменять цвет элемента Move me на тот цвет, который соответствует новой позиции Start, In Progress или Done.
Пыталась реализовать циклом for по элементам placeholder, но ничего не выходит. Как это можно реализовать?
Вот мой код:

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const placeholders = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder');
item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
item.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row')

console.log(rows)


for (const placeholder of placeholders) {
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter);
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragleave', dragleave);
  placeholder.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}




function dragstart(event) {
  //console.log("dragstart", event.target);
  event.target.classList.add('hold');
  setTimeout(() => event.target.classList.add('hide'), 0)

};

function dragend(event) {
  //console.log("dragend", event.target);
  item.classList.remove('hold', 'hide');

}


function dragover(event) {
  //console.log('drag over')
  event.preventDefault()
}

function dragenter(event) {
  //console.log('drag enter');
  event.target.classList.add('hovered');
}

function dragleave(event) {
  //console.log('drag leave');
  event.target.classList.remove('hovered');

}

function drop(event) {
  //console.log('drag drop')
  event.target.append(item); // drop element in a specific position
  event.target.classList.remove('hovered');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.col-header {
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.36);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.36);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #f7f6f7;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  color: #828282;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: grab;
}

.item:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 66px;
}

.start {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff85e4 0%, #229efd 179.25%);
}

.progress {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #209cff 0%, #68e0cf 100%);
}

.done {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f34646 0%, #f8e472 100%);
}

.hold {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #84faf4 0%, #e2f48f 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hovered {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(63, 196, 206, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Drag & Drop Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-header start">Start</div>
      <div class="col-header progress">In Progress</div>
      <div class="col-header done">Done</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="placeholder">
        <div class="item" draggable="true">Move me</div>
      </div>
      <div class="placeholder"></div>
      <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const placeholders = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder');
item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart);
item.addEventListener('dragend', dragend);

const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row')

//console.log(rows)

for (const placeholder of placeholders) {
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragover', dragover);
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter);
  placeholder.addEventListener('dragleave', dragleave);
  placeholder.addEventListener('drop', drop);
}

function dragstart(event) {
  //console.log("dragstart", event.target);
  event.target.classList.add('hold');
  setTimeout(() => event.target.classList.add('hide'), 0)
  event.target.classList.remove(event.target.closest('.placeholder').dataset.headerclass);
};

function dragend(event) {
  //console.log("dragend", event.target);
  item.classList.remove('hold', 'hide');
}

function dragover(event) {
  //console.log('drag over')
  event.preventDefault()
}

function dragenter(event) {
  //console.log('drag enter');
  event.target.classList.add('hovered');
}

function dragleave(event) {
  //console.log('drag leave');
  event.target.classList.remove('hovered');
}

function drop(event) {
  //console.log('drag drop')
  event.target.append(item); // drop element in a specific position
  event.target.classList.remove('hovered');
  event.target.querySelector('.item').classList.add(event.target.closest('.placeholder').dataset.headerclass);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.col-header {
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.36);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 66px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.36);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #f7f6f7;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  color: #828282;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: grab;
}

.item:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 66px;
}

.start {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff85e4 0%, #229efd 179.25%);
}

.progress {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #209cff 0%, #68e0cf 100%);
}

.done {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f34646 0%, #f8e472 100%);
}

.hold {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #84faf4 0%, #e2f48f 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.hovered {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(63, 196, 206, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Drag & Drop Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-header start">Start</div>
      <div class="col-header progress">In Progress</div>
      <div class="col-header done">Done</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="placeholder" data-headerclass="start">
        <div class="item" draggable="true">Move me</div>
      </div>
      <div class="placeholder" data-headerclass="progress"></div>
      <div class="placeholder" data-headerclass="done"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **обьясните пожалуйста что делает этот код **   `event.target.classList.remove(event.target.closest('.placeholder').dataset.headerclass);`

Comment: @VictoriaKhrobostova Убирает класс `start`, `progress` или `done` из элемента c `class="item"`.

Comment: а можете пожалуйста обьяснить что делает  dataset.headerclass в строчке `event.target.querySelector('.item').classList.add(event.target.closest('.placeholder').dataset.headerclass);`

Comment: @VictoriaKhrobostova Добавляет в `class="item"` значение атрибута `data-headerclass` из нового родителя.

Comment: **спасибо! очень помогли**

Comment: @VictoriaKhrobostova Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.